# How to consume a vector only once in multi threaded code

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency

I am trying to achieve the following, make a function that takes two arrays, one array of prereqs and one array of postreqs. The prereqs are registered such that when the last one finishes executing, it registers all the postreqs into a thread pool, it looks like this:

```rs
pub fn make_dependent<'a, T>(prereqs: Vec<T>, post_reqs: Vec<T>, pool: &ThreadPoolPtr)
where
    T: Fn(ThreadPoolPtr) + 'static,
{
    let finished = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(prereqs.len()));
    let post_reqs = Arc::new(post_reqs);

    for prereq in prereqs
    {
        let done_clone = finished.clone();
        let pool_clone = pool.clone();
        let post_reqs_clone = post_reqs.clone();
        pool.add_task(Task {
            job: Box::new(move |tp| {
                // Call the passed function.
                prereq(tp);

                let res = done_clone.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::Acquire);
                if res == 0
                {
                    for post_req in post_reqs_clone.as_ref()
                    {
                        pool_clone.add_task(Task {
                            job: Box::new(post_req),
                        })
                    }
                }
            }),
        })
    }
}
```

The problem here is, the iteration is over references, and their lifetimes do not live long enough, so the compiler complaints, but I cannot directly consume the functions, because each prereq needs to know about each post req. So I seem to be trapped in a loop, I can't use references due to lifetimes, but I cannot consume semantically because all prereqs need to know what to consume if they happen to be the last one to terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [`Arc::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.into_inner) which is guaranteed to return the inner value if and only if there are no other clones remaining, i.e. guaranteed for the last `prereq` to conclude.

As a side benefit, you can get rid of the `finished` atomic counter and rely on the `Arc`'s inner counter to identify the last worker. However you need a `Mutex` to guard from a potential race condition if all the worker threads finish before the parent thread has released its clone of `post_reqs`:

```
pub fn make_dependent<'a, T>(prereqs: Vec<T>, post_reqs: Vec<T>, pool: &ThreadPoolPtr)
where
    T: Fn(ThreadPoolPtr) + 'static,
{
    let barrier = Arc::new(Mutex::<()>::new());
    let guard = barrier.lock();
    let post_reqs = Arc::new(post_reqs);

    for prereq in prereqs {
        let barrier = barrier.clone();
        let pool = pool.clone();
        let post_reqs = post_reqs.clone();
        pool.add_task(Task {
            job: Box::new(move |tp| {
                // Call the passed function.
                prereq(tp);

                barrier.lock(); // Ensures that the parent thread has released `post_reqs`
                if let Some(post_reqs) = Arc::into_inner(post_reqs) {
                    for post_req in post_reqs {
                        pool.add_task(Task {
                            job: Box::new(post_req),
                        })
                    }
                }
            }),
        })
    }
    // Not strictly necessary since the automatic drop order guarantees
    // that `post_reqs` will be dropped before `guard` since it was allocated
    // after.
    drop(post_reqs);
    drop(guard);
}
```

Comment: @cafce25 note that your edit has added some differences from the OP's code that are unrelated to issue…

Comment: Well yes, but this being the more idiomatic version and even you getting confused by  `barrier_clone` vs `barrier` and using `pos_reqs` instead of `post_reqs_clone`, I believe answers should be as idiomatic as possible, they're more likely to be copied into production code after all.

Comment: @cafce25 I am concerned about the mutex. My understanding is that atomic syncing has a lower impact on performance than locking a mutex Menaing, with my current knowledge I am still biased towards using the finished atomic counter.

Comment: @Makogan Note that even with an explicit `finished` counter, you need the `Mutex` to make sure that the parent thread drops its copy of `post_reqs` before the worker threads, or you need to duplicate the code that registers the `post_reqs` tasks in the parent thread. Moreover since it is very unlikely that the `Mutex` will be contended, pinging a `Mutex` like I do has about the same performance as decrementing an atomic (i.e. negligible impact since it's only done once anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using an `Arc<Mutex<Option<Vec<T>>>>`.  You would need to replace the line wrapping `post_reqs` in an `Arc` to also wrap it in the other layers:

```
let post_reqs = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(post_reqs)));
```

Now, in your code that wants to consume the vector, you can lock the `Mutex` and [take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) it out of the `Option`:

```
let post_reqs = post_reqs_clone.lock().unwrap().take().unwrap();
for post_req in post_reqs {
    // ...
}
```